# Symfony2 - Image path in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, symfony

I'm trying to dynamically load an image from a javascript file.

How I can load it using Assets (or FOSJsRoutingBundle) without having to paste my code of the .js file into the template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could post PHP generated JS variable and later use it in you JS files.

for example:

```
<script>
var image_path = '{{ asset('your/path/to/image') }}';
</script>
```

in case you need this path in the  section, where typically JS files are included, you can always use twig blocks.